# Debugging C++ DLL used by C# Project

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a C# project that uses a C++ DLL. I am trying to debug the DLL but Visual Studio is reporting that the "PDB does not match image" for my DLL.

- The C++ DLL is built by me, in the same solution which produces both the DLL and a full PDB.
- The C++ DLL is marked as a dependency of the C# project.
- The C# project it set up to copy the DLL file to the output directory if it is newer than the existing ones.
- The C# project has "Enable debugging of native code" enabled.

The symbol load information for the DLL under the modules window shows the correct PDB is found but complains that the "PDB does not match image". Even though this is the PDB built along side the DLL by Visual Studio.

Googling this error only provides people also asking what's going wrong but an answer is never provided.

Comment: When something strange like this is happening I would do the following: 1. Search for all instances of the dll by name under solution and in the PATH and remove them all. Search for all dll pdb files and remove them as well. Rebuild dll project using the configuration to be debugged only (x64/Debug for example). 2. rebuild c# project and try to debug again. In most cases the error was caused by using version of the dll different from what I was thinking is being used.

Comment: Separate project do not have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the copying of the DLL.

I had added the DLL as an "Existing Item" to the C# project which apparently copies the file into the project directory as is. I had to add a post-build event to the C++ project to copy the DLL to the C# project's directory. Which will then copy the DLL to the output directory if it is newer.